# What is in simple words blocking IO and non-blocking IO?

Tags: io

How would you explain a simple mortal about blocking IO and non-blocking IO? I've found these concepts are not very clear among many of us programmers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blocking I/O means that the program execution is put on hold while the I/O is going on. So the program waits until the I/O is finished and then continues it's execution.
In non-blocking I/O the program can continue during I/O operations.

Comment: ... and is the notified via a callback when the IO operation is finished. This forces you to design your programs differently, but will make them perform a lot better.

Comment: @Lex,any example for blocking and nonblocking operation? Thanks.

Comment: @etc_passwd In JS it's simple to understand; a call to `alert();` is blocking, since executing is put on hold until the user clicks OK. An AJAX call is non-blocking, execution of is continued while the HTTP request is being sent.

Answer (score 4):

It's a concurrency issue.  In the normal case, after an OS kernel receives an I/O op from a user program, that program does not run again until the I/O operation completes. Other programs typically get scheduled in the meantime.

This solves lots of little problems. For example, how does a program know how many bytes were read unless the I/O is complete when the `read(2)` returns? How does it know if it can reuse a `write(2)` buffer if the operation is still in progress when `write(2)` returns? Obviously, a more complex interface is needed for truely asynchronous I/O.

Ultimately it comes down to:

1. I/O happens synchronously with respect to the program, by blocking the program until I/O is finished
2. I/O is merely scheduled by a system call, and some notification mechanism exists to communicate the real result
3. There is a compromise where I/O ops simply fail if they can't be completed immediately. This is the more common use of "non-blocking" I/O in practice.

The whole issue is complicated moreover by the effort to schedule multithreaded programs when I/O could conceivably block only one thread, but that's a different question...

Answer (score 0):

simply said .. the non blocking i/o (Asynchronous) allows other operations to be carried out while it does its thing and blocking i/o would block other operations